# Creating a converter for STP to OBJ

Tags: export, .obj, step

I'm trying to create an application that converts STEP(stp) files to OBJ files. The OBJ format is quite simple and creating a reader/writer for that wont be any problem but the STEP format is more complicated. Is it possible to make it myself without too much problem or do you have any other suggestions to approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using FreeCAD after all. It cant convert with materials and the meshes gets worse and the files are bigger than converting from 3DS Max. Converting the OBJ files from FreeCAD and then to FBX(which was the goal format) ended up with a pretty good mesh. It still has no material but that is not important for me

Answer (score 1):

FreeCAD can convert STEP to OBJ.

Comment: It can, but very poorly. FreeCAD doesnt read the materials and is smoothing everything out

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use free tool [CAD Assistant](https://opencascade.com/content/cad-assistant) (which is also based on Open CASCADE Technology as FreeCAD) for converting STEP files into OBJ with *color information preserved*.